# Iterating over pandas df returning all values not matchin a regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I am trying to iterate over a columns to identify non-valid entries. This works

```
weirdos = df.loc[df[column] == '7282'][['col1', 'col2']]
```

but trying the same with regex like

```
regex = "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[*]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[*]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9*]{0,30}$"
weirdos = df.loc[re.search(regex, df[column]) is not None][['col1', 'col2']]
```

keeps getting the error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `column` (which is not enclosed in a pair of quotes `'`) is a string variable containing the column name to check, use:

```
weirdos = df.loc[~df[column].str.contains(regex)][['col1', 'col2']]
```

Note that you have to use `str.contains()` instead of `str.match()` in order to adhere to your original code using `re.search()`.  This is because `str.contains()` underlying uses `re.search()` while `str.match()` uses `re.match()` which search for matches at the beginning of text only.

The `~` is added in the filtering condition because of your question title mentioning **NOT matching a regex**  You can remove it if you intend for matching instead.

One reminder is to define the regex under raw string, i.e.  `regex = r'....'` so that you don't need to escape each regex symbol.

### Test Run

```
data = {'col_0': ['baa', 'bbc', 'ccd'], 'col1': [10, 20, 30], 'col2': [100, 200, 300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
Output:
    col_0   col1    col2
0   baa       10     100
1   bbc       20     200
2   ccd       30     300

regex = r'aa'           # containing 'aa' anywhere in string
column = 'col_0'

weirdos = df.loc[~df[column].str.contains(regex)][['col1', 'col2']]     # filtering those NOT containing 'aa' anywhere in string
print(weirdos)

Output:
    col1    col2
1   20       200
2   30       300
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for the detailled answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['foo','buz','foz'],'B':range(3)})
df.loc[df['A'].str.match(r'^f')]['B']
```